# Remote connection to a Centos 7 machine which runs Cassandra 3.4

Tags: cassandra, remote-access, centos7, nosql

Changed the rpc_address, the nodetool status display the ip of the machine, rpc_port is default 9160. Locally i can cqlsh without any problems via port 9042. Also start_rpc is set to true. Allowed both ways connections in firewalld for 9160, the service is up and listening on 9160.

Despite all, each time i try from another machine :

cqlsh 149.5.XXX.XXX 9160 i get the :
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'149.5.xxx.xxx': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('149.5.xxx.xxx', 9160)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Any solutions guys? I`m growing white beard here because of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more information about Cassandra cluster like number of nodes and Cassandra distribution? If you have more than 1 node cluster, are other nodes able to connect to it?

Comment: Can you try connecting it using Devcenter. http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-devcenter/devcenter/dcInstallation.html

Comment: Can you please check the status of firewall and if it's active, turn off the firewall and then try connecting it?

Comment: Single node on single machine. Datastax 3.4 on Centos 7. Disabled also Selinux, restarted Cassandra service, still unable to connect. Going to research some more about Devcenter @Abhinandan.

Comment: The firewalld has the port 9160 declared to allow both ways communication. I will try also to disable it to check if i can make the connection

Comment: Please make sure you have configured the "cassandra.yaml" correctly.https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Comment: firewalld is the problem. with firewalld disabled i was able to establish a remote connection. Strange part is that it went on :9042. Declared the 9042 in firewalld as permanent tcp and is working now. Going to check also with selinux enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are able to access that port from remote machine.You can use **telnet** for that.

I will recommend you to check the **status of firewall** and if it's active, turn it off or open the port to which you are trying to connect and then try connecting it from remote machine.

Comment: You can have the connection also with firewalld running. Just declare the port 9042 "sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=9042/tcp" and "sudo firewall-cmd --reload" and "sudo service cassandra restart". Selinux can be left enforcing.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of cqlsh use 9042 port to connect to cassandra server.

9160 port is used by older versions of cassandra, which is rpc/thift port now.

So, you need to enable both the ports in firewall, and since you are using newer version, you don't need to specify port it will default to 9042 for server.